# What do we call this in python?

Tags: python, loops, variables, for-loop

Consider the following for loop:

```
for x in range(0, 3):
    print "We're on time %d" % (x)
```

I can't seem to find the proper name of the `x` in the for loop. I know it is essentially a sort of arbitrary placeholder but I'd be interested in knowing the proper name if anyone does know.

Comment: Don't understand exactly what you mean. X is a local variable, only accessible inside the for loop. "Index" may be??

Comment: @Jorge The iteration variable is local to the *function*, and not just the loop.  It is accessible outside the loop also and could have been defined before the for loop.  The situation is different for comprehensions in 3.x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct name is "iteration variable", aka "iterating var" if you don't mind bad grammar.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax in the python 2 [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html) gives:

```
for_stmt ::=  "for" target_list "in" expression_list ":" suite
              ["else" ":" suite]
```

and then:

"*The suite may assign to the variable(s) in the target list;*"

So `x` in your example is a variable.

The Python 3 [version](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/compound_stmts.html) is worded slightly differently:

"*The for-loop makes assignments to the variables(s) in the target list.*"

But you can see that it still calls them variables.

Answer (score 1):

`x` is a variable, or "iteration variable", if you will, which, for a python `for` loop is a placeholder for each individual member of an iterable (basically a container to hold an arbitrary number of a data type), and `range()` is an iterator (as oppposed to previous versions of python, where it was a list), which returns its unique iterable data type, which is, functionally speaking, like a list where every member is destroyed after its use to preserve memory.

Answer (score 0):

It's obvious that `x` is just a variable since it is varied in each iteration of for-loop. The range of its variation is in (0,3), and the value for each iteration is from 0 to 2. (local var / iteration var)

Answer (score -4):

It is a variable, perhaps made easier to understand when you view the loop in generator format.

[Generator image](http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_images/listComprehensions.gif)

Comment: Iterator is complete different beast.

Comment: Your edit isn't much of an answer, although it is certainly more correct.